# What kind of cable should I buy to connect to these connectors coming out of the wall?

Tags: light, wire

Someone stole the fluorescent tube light in my apartment that was rented out. What is left is these 2 cables poking out the side. I am trying to find some sort of extension cord to connect to the black and red cables and I will wire it into the fluorescent tube light. Any idea what kind of extension cord/ connector will fit?[image]

Thanks for your help.

Comment: A “cable” is several “wires” inside a sheath.  That looks like standard AU/NZ wiring (or older UK) and the 2 wires hook up to comparable colored wires in the new fixture.  It looks like they put crimps on just to insulate them, which is more care than you expect from a thief.  Those can be removed and the bared ends of the wires can be put on the binding posts inside the new light.   FWIW I find fluorescent fixtures are going out of style fast, and I get them free by the dozen on Craigslist and other free/cycle places.

Comment: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=inline+insulated+crimp+connector&ia=images&iax=images

Comment: I get fluorescent fixtures T8 & T12 also I remove the ballast and lamps then direct wire T8 led tubes , more light less power usage with 50k hours life expectancies these will outlive me.

Comment: Thank you all for your help. Appreciate it. This property is in AU.